# Help in evaluating $\displaystyle\int\ \cos^2\Big(\arctan\big(\sin\left(\text{arccot}(x)\right)\big)\Big)\ \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Is there an easy way to prove this result?

> $$\int\ \cos^2\Big(\arctan\big(\sin\left( \text{arccot}(x)\right)\big)\Big)\ \text{d}x = x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

I tried some substitutions but I got nothing helpful, like:

- $x = \cot (z)$

I also tried the crazy one:

- $x = \cot(\arcsin(\tan(\arccos(z))))$

Any hint?

Thank you!

Comment: First hint : $\sin(arccot(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ (for positive $x$).

Comment: Drawing triangles really helps.

Comment: This really looks like the consequence of a series of trigonometric identities, more than some particular integration technique.

Comment: Second hint : $\cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Comment: @Peter : Could you type $\cos(\arctan(x))$ instead of $\cos(arctan(x))$.  The latter doesn't have proper spacing in things like $a\arctan b$ or $a\arctan(b)$ (and I include both of those examples so you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, draw the triangles.  You have
$$
\frac x 1 = x = \cot\theta = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}}
$$
so if you have a triangle in which $\text{opposite}=1$ and $\text{adjacent} = x$ then you have $\text{hypotenuse} = \sqrt{x^2+1}$ and so
$$
\sin\theta = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
so
$$
\sin\operatorname{arccot} x = \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+1}}.
$$
Then do a similar thing with the cosine of the arctangent.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

$\alpha = \cot^{-1} x\\
\beta = \tan^{-1} (\sin \alpha)$

Use trig indentities to find $\csc \alpha$ and $\sin \alpha$

$\sin\alpha = \tan \beta$

Use similar identities to find $\sec \beta$ and $\cos\beta$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**
$$\cos \left(\arctan \left(x\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}$$
So
$$\begin{align}
\\& \int \:\left(\cos \left(\arctan \left(\sin \left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)^2dx
\\& = \int \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}dx
\\& = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2}x-\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+C}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

After using trigonometry, you should be able to get

$$\cos(\arctan(\sin( \text{arccot}(x)))) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x^2+2}}$$

From there, I'd assume it's just a trig sub problem.

Comment: From there is really trivial. I am now curious to get that identity. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'll do half of it, the rest of it is done in a very similiar way. Let $\theta = \text{arccot}(x)$, then $\cot(\theta) = x$, and hence using right triangles we've $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is equal to $$\int 1-\frac{1}{2+x^2} \, dx$$ this is now easy to integrate.

Comment: This is a hint. Please mark it as a hint!

Comment: That is cool, but can you prove this identity? Does it holds for all $x$?

Comment: Its not a hint, its a concise solution.

Comment: @FourierTransform Yes, for example $\cos^2x=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2x}$, this removes the first iteration, the second is similar.